# Why JDialog doesn't close after JOptionPane showMessageDialog?

Tags: java, dialog, joptionpane, jdialog

When my server app is starting, a `JDialog` opens to indicate to the user that the app is loading. But between the opening of `JDialog` and its closing, I use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` to display another message.

The problem is, if I display this new message before closing `JDialog` then `JDialog` will never close even if I close `JOptionPane` dialog. If I remove the `JOptionPane` dialog then the `JDialog` closes as usual.

**Why opening `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` disable `JDialog` closing ?**

Is use this code to open `JDialog`:

```
final JDialog dlg = new JDialog(this, "Veuillez patienter, le serveur démarre...", true);
dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
dlg.setSize(300, 75);
dlg.setResizable(false);
dlg.setLocationRelativeTo(this);         
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
    dlg.setVisible(true);
});
t.start();
```

And this code to close it:

```
dlg.setVisible(false);
```

And between these lines of code I do this to open message dialog:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, String.format(I18n.i18n.getString("PopupWifiCreated"), this.SSID, this.password), null, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion setting the visibility of any frame to false is not the greatest idea. Of course it depends what are your goals, but I'd still not recommend it. It should be done like e.g.:

```
    dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    dlg.close();
or
    dlg.dispose();
```

If it still wont work, try to reverse the order of dialogs - first show messageDialog, and then JDialog.

Comment: Well, you are right about doing `dlg.dispose();` rather than `dlg.setVisible(false);` but that's not solving my issue at all.

Comment: And of course I can't invert the order of dialogs, it does not make sense.

Comment: What is `JDialog#close` ?